# Can't access UIImageView if created programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

If I create a `UIImageView` via Storyboard and add it as a `@property` into a `ViewController.h`, I can access that `UIImageView` from anywhere in the `ViewController.m` via `[self UIImageView]` or `self.UIImageView`.

But If I create the `UIImageView` programmatically from `viewDidLoad` as you see below, I seem to lose the ability to access it from outside `viewDidLoad`.

```
UIImageView *prevImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImageView *currImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImageView *nextImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

NSArray *imageViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:prevImgView, currImgView, nextImgView, nil];

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview: scrollView];

CGRect cRect = scrollView.bounds;
UIImageView *cView;

for (int i=0; i<imageViews.count; i++) {
    cView = [imageViews objectAtIndex:i];
    cView.frame = cRect;
    [scrollView addSubview:cView];
    cRect.origin.x += cRect.size.width;
}
```

So later on if I want to modify the image that is being displayed in any one of the `UIImageView` I've created from `viewDidLoad`, I can't seem to access it. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create your UIImageView in your header file and then it would be available throughout the rest of the view.  You will need to add it to the view in viewDidLoad though.

```
         Header
         UIImageView *image;

         Main // ViewDidLoad
         image = [UIImageView alloc] .....
         [self.view addSubView image];


         Main Function .....
         [image setImage ....
```

Comment: No not at all, if you create it programmatically in the header file, initialize it in the viewDidLoad and add it to the view, you will be able to access it anywhere in the view, but you NEED to add it to the view

Answer (score 1):

The answer AgnosticDev is trying to say here is to add an ivar to your view controller's .h file... e.g.:

```
@implementation YHLViewController : ViewController
{
    UIImageView * currImageView;
}
```

And then in your "`viewDidLoad`" method, you can allocate and initialize it via:

```
currImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

and have access to it from anywhere else in your view controller.