# Not able to access programmatically created UIView from outside of the method it is created in

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview

this may be a really stupid question but I have created a UIView programmatically but I don't seem to be able to access it anywhere is in the code apart from the actual method that it is in (for example to remove it from the superview or to modify the view).

This is the code I used to create the UIView:

```
CGRect frame;
frame.size = CGSizeMake((gameView.bounds.size.width-50), 400);
frame.origin.x = 25;
frame.origin.y = 130;

UIView *endGameView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
endGameView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:235.0f/255.0f
                                           green:235.0f/255.0f
                                            blue:235.0f/255.0f
                                           alpha:1.0f];

[gameView addSubview:endGameView];
```

Answer (score 0):

***Another way to access the view***

You can set a tag (1024 for example) to `tag` property of endGameView, and you can fetch this view by send `viewWithTag:1024` message to its super view (gameView).

Tips: the tag should be unique in all subviews of its super view(gameView)

```
CGRect frame;
frame.size = CGSizeMake((gameView.bounds.size.width-50), 400);
frame.origin.x = 25;
frame.origin.y = 130;

UIView *endGameView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
endGameView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:235.0f/255.0f
                                           green:235.0f/255.0f
                                            blue:235.0f/255.0f
                                           alpha:1.0f];
endGameView.tag = 1024 ;

[gameView addSubview:endGameView];
```

fetch that view:

```
// fetch the view
UIView *endGameView = [gameView viewWithTag:1024] ;
[endGameView removeFromSuperView] ;
```

Answer (score -1):

found this [Can't access UIImageView if created programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544907/cant-access-uiimageview-if-created-programmatically) shortly after posting and it answered my question perfectly.

This is what I did to fix it:

```
Header
UIView *endGameView;

Main // ViewDidLoad
endGameView = [UIView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubView endGame View];

Creation Method

CGRect frame;
frame.size = CGSizeMake((gameView.bounds.size.width-50), 400);
frame.origin.x = 25;
frame.origin.y = 130;

endGameView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
endGameView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:235.0f/255.0f
                                           green:235.0f/255.0f
                                            blue:235.0f/255.0f
                                           alpha:1.0f];

[gameView addSubview: endGameView];
```